# short circuit operators give me different result

Tags: java

While using the short-circuit operators `&&` and `||`, I'm getting unexpected results.

```
    if(false && false || true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

It gives me `true` but according to short-circuit rule if the first operand is `false` then it is not necessary to evaluate the second operand. Can anyone explain it where I'm missing something.

Comment: You were correct if you wrote `if(false && (false || true))`

Comment: but why I'm getting the unexpected result. plz help

Comment: @Qadir Did you actually read ZouZou's comment?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped, it would be good to mark one of them as correct, so that future readers can benefit too :)

Answer (score 5):

```
(false && false) || true
```

is evaluated first. Short-circuit gives `false` and thus the `||` cannot be short-circuited, and is thus fully evaluated,

Answer (score 5):

My interpretation is that, because the `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||` (according to [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)), the statement gets interpreted as `(false && false) || true`.

This then evaluates to `false || true`, which is of course `true`. I could be wrong, but that's what seems to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the short circuit rules correctly.

The rule you stated applies to AND (&&) operation only.  Clearly the result of the first operation is false.  Now you need to perform the second operation OR (||).  The rule for OR is exact opposite, if first operand is TRUE the second doesn't need to be evaluated.  In your case the first operand is false, so second operand of || needs to be evaluated.  The result of second operand is true.  So the result of the whole expression is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think from `JDK 7` the short-circuit rule has been redefined because when I tried to run in `JDK 6` it gives me the correct answer but when I run it in `JDK 7` it gives me unexpected result.

Comment: I get true with Java 6 and 7.

Comment: Short circuit rules cannot be redefined in a way that the expression gives different result.  They are just optimization shortcuts.  The reason you have to be aware of them is if you have side effects in the methods used in expression, which is very bad coding style to begin with.